# Batch Scripting output format in table format

Tags: batch-file, scripting

I have created batch script as below, and i am using BALT utility to send this output on email.

```
set length=0 

FOR /f "tokens=1 delims=/" %%t IN ("%DATE%") DO SET TT=%%t 
FOR /f "tokens=2 delims=/" %%A IN ("%DATE%") DO SET DA=%%A 
FOR /f "tokens=3 delims=/" %%B IN ("%DATE%") DO SET DB=%%B 
FOR /f "tokens=4 delims=/" %%C IN ("%DATE%") DO SET DC=%%C 
for /F "tokens=1 delims=: " %%i in ('time /t') DO SET DD=%%i 
for /F "tokens=2 delims=: " %%j in ('time /t') DO SET DE=%%j 
for /F "tokens=3 delims=: " %%k in ('time /t') DO SET DF=%%k 

C: 
cd \siebserver\siebsrvr\BIN 

srvrmgr /g mt-wi-sblgatew:2320 /e siebelpro /u SADMIN /p Sadm1npw /i "C:\UJJ\comm.cfg" 

ren Status.csv status_old.csv
findstr /v /r /c:["srvrmgr"]["list"] status_old.csv > Status.csv

COPY Status.csv "C:\UJJ\Status.txt
del Status.csv 
exit
```

But the output looks like below:

```
SV_NAME    CC_ALIAS                   CP_NUM_RUN_TASKS  CP_MAX_TASKS  CP_ACTV_MTS_PROCS  CP_MAX_MTS_PROCS  CP_DISP_RUN_STATE  
---------  -------------------------  ----------------  ------------  -----------------  ----------------  -----------------  
sblprod01  eCommunicationsObjMgr_enu  11                100           4                  4                 Running            
sblprod02  eCommunicationsObjMgr_enu  9                 100           4                  4                 Running            
sblprod04  eCommunicationsObjMgr_enu  8                 100           4                  4                 Running            
sblprod03  eCommunicationsObjMgr_enu  16                100           4                  4                 Running            

4 rows returned.


SV_NAME    CC_ALIAS       CP_NUM_RUN_TASKS  CP_MAX_TASKS  CP_ACTV_MTS_PROCS  CP_MAX_MTS_PROCS  CP_DISP_RUN_STATE  
---------  -------------  ----------------  ------------  -----------------  ----------------  -----------------  
sblprod02  EAIObjMgr_enu  75                200           8                  8                 Running            
sblprod03  EAIObjMgr_enu  71                200           8                  8                 Running            
sblprod01  EAIObjMgr_enu  90                200           8                  8                 Running            
sblprod04  EAIObjMgr_enu  73                200           8                  8                 Running            

4 rows returned.

srvrmgr> spool off
spool off
```

How can i make this output in table format.

Comment: 1. please describe precisely how you want the output to look like; 2. it's never a good idea to query `%date%` and/or `%time%` multie times to get _one_ certain time stamp; 3. note that `date`/`time` return locale-dependent formats;

Comment: quote: "How can i make this output in table format." What you show is already a table format!

Comment: obviously he wants it in a comma separated way in a `.csv` for use in excel

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get an actual `.csv` file with commas instead of tabs and spaces this code should do the work. More realiable way of obtaining date information was added as well.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set length=0 
:: Obtaining date information
for /f "tokens=2 delims==+-" %%i in ('wmic os get localdatetime /value ^| findstr "="') do (
    set _date=%%i
    set YYYY=!_date:~0,4!
    set MM=!_date:~4,2!
    set DD=!_date:~6,2!
    set HH=!_date:~8,2!
    set Min=!_date:~10,2!
    set Sec=!_date:~12,2!
    set Mili=!_date:~-6!
)

cd \siebserver\siebsrvr\BIN 
srvrmgr /g mt-wi-sblgatew:2320 /e siebelpro /u SADMIN /p Sadm1npw /i "C:\UJJ\comm.cfg" 

ren Status.csv status_old.csv
findstr /v /r /c:["srvrmgr"]["list"] status_old.csv > Status.csv

::Replacing tabs and spaces with commas to obtain actual .csv file
set "output="
if exist status_mod.csv del status_mod.csv
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%i in ('findstr "_" status.csv') do (
    for %%j in (%%i) do (
        set "output=!output!%%j,"
    )
    echo !output:~0,-1! >> status_mod.csv
    set "output="
)

copy /y status_mod.csv "C:\UJJ\Status.txt"
del status_mod.csv
```

Comment: you should consider to also add `-` to the delimiters ( in the "wmic"-`for`)